# Form Submission to User and Admin - Magento, PHP and Zend Mail

Tags: php, email, magento, zend-framework

I'm working in Magento and new to PHP and Zend Mail.

The form was previously developed and was designed to send form submissions to 3 different email addresses. The email addresses are pulled from our Admin sections under "Contacts".

I wanted to add an automated response that the user receives after submitting our form.

It works, but the problem is the user receives 3 separate automated emails for each form submission. I'm sure you pro's will see why immediately when you see the code below.

Being a newbie, I'm hoping you guys/gals can help me with the code fix. Thanks in advance!

```
try {
    foreach($split as $multiemail){
        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->setBodyText($rq_msg);
        $mail->setBodyHtml($rq_msg);
        $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
        $mail->addTo($multiemail, $adminName);
        $mail->setSubject('New request from customer: '.$fromName);
        $mail->send();

        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->setBodyText($cust_msg);
        $mail->setBodyHtml($cust_msg);
        $mail->setFrom('our@email.com');
        $mail->addTo($fromEmail);
        $mail->setSubject('Your request was received, '.$fromName);
        $mail->send();
    }
} 
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMassage();
}

Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
    ->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')
    ->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to 
         as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.');

$this->_redirectUrl($request['redirecturl']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the user an email in a loop. Move the user email outside of the loop so that it only happens once.

```
<?php
    try {
        foreach ($split as $multiemail) {
            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->setBodyText($rq_msg);
            $mail->setBodyHtml($rq_msg);
            $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
            $mail->addTo($multiemail, $adminName);
            $mail->setSubject('New request from customer: ' . $fromName);
            $mail->send();           
        }

        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->setBodyText($cust_msg);
        $mail->setBodyHtml($cust_msg);
        $mail->setFrom('our@email.com');
        $mail->addTo($fromEmail);
        $mail->setSubject('Your request was received, ' . $fromName);
        $mail->send();

    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMassage();
    }

    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
    $this->_redirectUrl($request[ 'redirecturl' ]);
```

Comment: Awesome- works great. Thanks so much for your time and effort, bassxzero.